# Creating an image dataset using ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory gives different length for different batch size

Tags: python, keras

I created an image dataset for image classification. I used `flow_from_directory` for creating the dataset. In it's documentation it says, A DirectoryIterator yielding tuples of (x, y) where x is a numpy array containing a batch of images with shape (batch_size, *target_size, channels) and y is a numpy array of corresponding labels.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_path='rock_paper_scissors/rps'
val_path='rock_paper_scissors/rps-test-set'

train_data=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.0)

train=train_data.flow_from_directory(
    directory=train_path,
    target_size=(150,150),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=840
)

print(len(train))
```

There are a total of 840 images in each of the three sub-directories. When I set the batch_size to 840, `len(train)` = 3 but when batch_size is set to 600, `len(train)` = 5.
Why is that ? Shouldn't it be 3 as well ?

Comment: No, the length of the generator is the number of batches, it will increase if you reduce the batch size.

Comment: That's what I asked

Comment: The number of batches is computed as the total length of the dataset divided by the batch size (rounded up to an integer), plug the numbers and you will see how it behaves.